# What are 'The cobweb clues of Rosamond'?

Tags: poetry, ralph-waldo-emerson

I came across a rather good poem by **Ralph Waldo Emerson** today. It's called simply **'April'**. It's just a bit too long to post in full here, but [here's a link](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/a/amverse/BAD1982.0001.001/1:6.32?rgn=div2;view=fulltext).

I was a bit confused by these lines:

> The hedge is gemmed with diamonds,
> The air with Cupids full,
> The cobweb clues of Rosamond
> Guide lovers to the pool.

What are these **'cobweb clues of Rosamond'**? It reads as if it's referring to a myth or legend I haven't been told about, and I can't find any Rosamonds, Rosamunds or Rosamundes who did anything famous with spiders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rosamund is [Rosamund Clifford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosamund_Clifford), Henry II's mistress.  Legends claim that his wife, Eleanor, tracked her down to the heart of a maze that Henry had hidden her in and killed her.  Sometimes, the legends specify that she followed a piece of thread that Rosamund had let fall behind her, and which then rolled out as she ran.

Therefore, this is saying that the cobwebs are like that thread.